# How to use Latex in new Jekyll? (Gem-based theme minima)

Tags: html, ruby, github, latex, jekyll

Both https://jekyllrb.com/docs/extras/ and http://www.gastonsanchez.com/visually-enforced/opinion/2014/02/16/Mathjax-with-jekyll/ require `_layout` directory, which couldn't found. Kramdown https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#block-boundaries although has been set in `_config.yml` doesn't work either.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

In Jekyll _layout is where the layout for your Jekyll website is stored. When using a theme it uses the layout file for that theme. Any file which you add in the _layout folder will override the theme layout files.

1. To modify the default layout which came with the theme you are using you need to first make a _layout folder and then create a blank default.html.
2. Then find the github repository of your theme and copy the html from _layout/default.html into your file
3. Add the LaTex script code you need to the header.

The github docs on customizing a Jekyll theme. https://help.github.com/articles/customizing-css-and-html-in-your-jekyll-theme/#customizing-your-jekyll-themes-html-layout

Comment: But I couldn't find `_layout/default.html` in my current repo? For example, at garyzhubc.github.io

Comment: @ZHU You need to create a new folder called _layout and create a blank file it in called default.html. Copy the https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/master/_layouts/default.html (this is the default.html from your theme) into the file you have just made. Then add the latex script code into the header of the new default.html file.

Comment: Thanks! So it would be something like `<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ page.lang | default: site.lang | default: "en" }}">

  {%- include head.html -%}

  <body>

    {%- include header.html -%}

    <main class="page-content" aria-label="Content">
      <div class="wrapper">
        {{ content }}
      </div>
    </main>

    {%- include footer.html -%}

  </body>

</html>` am I correct?

Comment: You need to move the script into the html code. In your case the easiest place would be at the top of the body so  `<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="{{ page.lang | default: site.lang | default: "en" }}"> {%- include head.html -%} <body> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"> </script> {%- include header.html -%} <main class="page-content" aria-label="Content"> <div class="wrapper"> {{ content }} </div> </main> {%- include footer.html -%} </body> </html>`

Comment: It still shows nothing when I was trying to make a posts `$E(X)$`. For example in my GitHub page `https://garyzhubc.github.io/rs/2018/06/15/rejection-sampling.html` nothing appears.

Comment: IMPORTANT: 
https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/configuration.html#loading-mathjax-from-a-cdn

Answer (score 1):

The best solution so far that I know to include something similar to LaTeX (it's not real TeX code) are MathJax and KaTeX. I prefer the latter but it's obliviously a matter of personal tasting.

For both of them, as stated in [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51001619/4691498) you need to modify some file in the `_layout` folder. Assuming that you currently use minima template, just copy the `_layout` folder in your project folder and do the modification you need. To find where your minima template is, just run in your project folder the command

```
bundle show minima
```

In order to use MathJax, you could follow the [getting started guide](https://www.mathjax.org/#gettingstarted). That is, simply put the following in your head.

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/latest.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML' async></script>
```

Obviously, you could configure it in order to have something more but this is sufficient to get you to start.

Include KaTeX instead is a bit more troublesome since the formulas are usually rendered server side. So you have to execute it inside Jekyll. There are several plugins that simplify the inclusion. In my case, the one that works best was [jekyll-katek-block](https://github.com/drewsberry/jekyll-katex-block). Basically, the only steps needed are:

1. Put [`katex_block.rb`](https://github.com/drewsberry/jekyll-katex-block/blob/master/katex_block.rb) in `_plugins` folder
2. Store `katex.min.js` anywhere on your website. The default is `/public/js/katex.min.js`, otherwise you have to modify your `_config.yml` adding

   ```
   katex:
     path_to_js: "./your/path/to/katex/js"
   ```
3. (almost optional) Link `katek.min.css` and fonts.

`katex.min.js`, `katex.min.css`, and fonts can be downloaded from [KaTeX GitHub page](https://khan.github.io/KaTeX/). Like MathJax, you could also configure KaTeX a bit. Follow the KaTeX GitHub page to see how you could recompile from scratch the `katex.min.css` file to include the changes you need.